# simple Redshift query with over window function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to somehow optimize query like this on redshift?

```
with all_events as (
  select
  env_id
  , device_class
  , device_environment_type
  , device_make
  , device_model
  , user_agent
  , sys_first_arrival_timestamp
  , row_number() over (partition by env_id order by sys_first_arrival_timestamp desc) as event_num
from device_events
where device_class in ('Desktop', 'Mobile')
)

select *
from all_events
where event_num = 1
```

The device_events table is huge and this query takes ages to execute. The slow part is that window function call, I wonder if I am missing something, I am only interested in the first event for each env_id.

Comment: What are the distribution key and sort keys for this table?  A bit part of the work that the window function needs to do is partitioning the data by env_id and then sort by sys_first_arrival_timestamp.

Comment: you could try, to make two UNION queries in the first te and add a row_number in a second, the concept is that a IN clause is basically an OR clause and so the indx on device_class  wouldn't get into effect.